# Why are all my composables being recomposed?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

I am creating a screen with a color picker. Here's the code for the whole screen, including the color picker code. The reason why I'm including the whole screen's code instead of just the color picker's is because I want to give more context.

```kotlin
package com.gitlab.djsushi123.kingenscoreboard.presentation.screen.newplayer

import androidx.compose.animation.animateColorAsState
import androidx.compose.animation.core.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ArrowBack
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Check
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.scale
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.KeyboardCapitalization
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.navigation.NavHostController
import com.gitlab.djsushi123.kingenscoreboard.domain.model.Player
import com.google.accompanist.systemuicontroller.SystemUiController
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import org.koin.androidx.compose.getViewModel

@Composable
fun NewPlayerScreen(
    viewModel: NewPlayerScreenViewModel = getViewModel(),
    appNavController: NavHostController,
    systemUiController: SystemUiController,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    val state = viewModel.state

    val animatedSelectedColor by animateColorAsState(
        targetValue = state.playerColor,
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 600)
    )

    val primaryVariantColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primaryVariant
    val darkIconsDisposable = MaterialTheme.colors.isLight

    val useDarkIcons = with(animatedSelectedColor) {
        (red + green + blue) / 3f > 0.5f
    }

    DisposableEffect(key1 = animatedSelectedColor) {
        systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(
            color = animatedSelectedColor,
            darkIcons = useDarkIcons
        )

        onDispose {
            systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(
                color = primaryVariantColor,
                darkIcons = darkIconsDisposable
            )
        }
    }

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopBar(
                color = animatedSelectedColor,
                onColor = if (useDarkIcons) Color.Black else Color.White,
                saveButtonEnabled = state.saveButtonEnabled,
                onBackButtonClicked = { appNavController.popBackStack() },
                onSave = {
                    val player = Player(
                        name = state.playerName,
                        abbreviation = state.playerAbbreviation,
                        color = state.playerColor
                    )
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        viewModel.savePlayer(player)
                        appNavController.popBackStack()
                    }
                }
            )
        },
        modifier = modifier
    ) { paddingValues ->
        Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.surface, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()) // so that we can scroll with the keyboard open
                    .padding(paddingValues)
                    .padding(start = 8.dp, top = 8.dp, end = 8.dp)
            ) {
                // Player name field with error
                OutlinedTextField(
                    value = state.playerName,
                    onValueChange = {
                        viewModel.onEvent(
                            NewPlayerFormEvent.PlayerNameChanged(name = it)
                        )
                    },
                    isError = state.playerNameError != null,
                    label = { Text(text = "Name") },
                    placeholder = { Text(text = "John Cena") },
                    singleLine = true,
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                        capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.Words
                    ),
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                )
                Text(
                    text = state.playerNameError ?: "",
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.error,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.End,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                )

                // Player abbreviation field
                OutlinedTextField(
                    value = state.playerAbbreviation,
                    onValueChange = {
                        viewModel.onEvent(
                            NewPlayerFormEvent.PlayerAbbreviationChanged(abbreviation = it)
                        )
                    },
                    isError = state.playerAbbreviationError != null,
                    label = { Text(text = "Abbreviation") },
                    singleLine = true,
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                        capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.Characters,
                        autoCorrect = false
                    ),
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                )
                Text(
                    text = state.playerAbbreviationError ?: "",
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.error,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.End,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                ColorPicker(
                    selected = state.playerColor,
                    onSelect = { color ->
                        viewModel.onEvent(
                            NewPlayerFormEvent.PlayerColorChanged(color = color)
                        )
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun TopBar(
    color: Color,
    onColor: Color,
    saveButtonEnabled: Boolean,
    onBackButtonClicked: () -> Unit,
    onSave: () -> Unit
) {
    val saveButtonAlpha by animateFloatAsState(
        if (saveButtonEnabled) ContentAlpha.high else ContentAlpha.disabled
    )

    TopAppBar(
        title = { Text(text = "New player", color = onColor) },
        navigationIcon = {
            IconButton(onClick = onBackButtonClicked) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
                    contentDescription = "Back",
                    tint = onColor
                )
            }
        },
        actions = {
            IconButton(onClick = onSave, enabled = saveButtonEnabled) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.Check,
                    contentDescription = "Save",
                    tint = onColor.copy(alpha = saveButtonAlpha)
                )
            }
        },
        backgroundColor = color
    )
}

@Composable
private fun ColorPicker(
    selected: Color,
    onSelect: (color: Color) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val colors: List<Color> = remember {
        (0..340 step 8).map { hue ->
            Color.hsl(hue = hue.toFloat(), saturation = 0.5f, lightness = 0.5f)
        }.dropLast(3)
    }

    Column(modifier = modifier) {
        for (row in 0..(colors.size - 1) / 4) {
            Row(
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                for (tile in 0 until 4) {
                    val color = colors[row * 4 + tile]
                    ColorPickerTile(
                        color = color,
                        selected = color == selected,
                        onClick = { onSelect(color) },
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .width(70.dp)
                            .height(70.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ColorPickerTile(
    color: Color,
    selected: Boolean,
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    shape: Shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val scale = remember { Animatable(initialValue = 1f) }
    val borderWidth by animateDpAsState(
        targetValue = if (selected) 6.dp else 0.dp,
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 350)
    )

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = selected) {
        if (selected) {
            launch {
                scale.animateTo(
                    targetValue = 0.90f,
                    animationSpec = tween(
                        durationMillis = 50
                    )
                )
                scale.animateTo(
                    targetValue = 1f,
                    animationSpec = spring(
                        dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioLowBouncy,
                        stiffness = Spring.StiffnessLow
                    )
                )
            }
        } else {
            launch { scale.animateTo(1f) }
        }
    }

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .scale(scale.value)
            .border(
                width = borderWidth,
                color = if (borderWidth.value == 0f) Color.Transparent else MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface,
                shape = shape
            )
            .clip(shape)
            .background(color = color)
            .clickable(onClick = onClick)
    )
}
```

My color picker is composed of `ColorPickerTile`s, which are stacked in a grid that is 4 tiles wide. This grid is a made-up grid from `Row`s inside a big `Column`. My problem is related to performance. When we check the "layout inspector" tab in Android Studio, we can see that when the user selects a different color tile in the app, every single `ColorPickerTile` gets recomposed MULTIPLE TIMES because of an animation I've added. I don't understand why this is necessary and why is this even possible, since the `ColorPickerTile` composable is restartable and also skippable and none of its parameters changed AFAIK. Here's a screenshot of what I mean:

[image: Recomposition counts]

The fact that these recompositions happen for every single `ColorPickerTile` many times during an animation means that the whole animation lags, especially on low-end devices. And the lag increases exponentially, with more `ColorPickerTile`s. My question is, what is causing these useless recompositions? And how would I go about solving the issue?

Comment: My expectation is because of the animation.  Since it's animated in both branches of the else, it will always need to recompose to do the animation.  Try putting the animation only on the selected==true branch to test.  If so, what you want to do is save some extra state and remember the previous selected as well as the current, and only animate those 2 tiles-  those are the only 2 that may need it.  Or just drop the animation alltogether.    Honestly this is one of the weak areas of a compose-like UI-  animations are more easily done in a view system where you have more control.

Comment: Hey Gabe, thanks for your answer. I don't really understand what you mean by "putting the animation on the selected==true" branch. Could you please explain it a little bit more?

Comment: Right now in your code you have an if/else branch which adds an animation in the if and the else.  Remove it from the else, and see if it drops the number of recomposed items.  If so, then the problem is that animating the items, even if the animation will immediately end because they're already the right scale, is a problem.  In that case change to only animating the 2 tiles that need it.

Comment: Okay, I've tried it out, it didn't help. The composables are still being recomposed.

Comment: `selected` does change and therefore compose will recompose all the places where it is read

Comment: @vitidev which `selected`? In the `ColorPickerTile` or `ColorPicker`?

Comment: `selected = color == selected` for `ColorPickerTile`

Comment: @vitidev yes, it does change, but only when you select/deselect a specific tile. It doesn't change otherwise.

Comment: I do not understand what the problem is. Everything works properly - in the new current element recomposition occurs due to animation, in the old one, due to animation too . The remaining elements are not recomposed. Everything is fine (well, except that aunch in LaunchedEffect is not needed)

Comment: Well... The remaining elements *are* recomposed. That's my whole issue. I don't understand why.

Comment: Isolated ColorPicker works fine (check for yourself to eliminate the bug android studio)
So you need to add logging to ColorPickerTile to see what color value comes there during recomposition

Comment: @vitidev thank you very much, I fixed it. Basically, I had to remove the `DisposableEffect` from the `NewPlayerScreen` composable.